# MUI theme's styleOverrides don't override?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to migrate from MUI 4 to 5, but my app is suddenly very ugly! A key problem is that many of the theme properties don't work because they are being overridden ... by the defaults. For instance, given this theme:

```js
export const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        mode: 'dark',
    },
    components: {
        MuiButtonBase: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    textTransform: 'none',
                    color: 'red',
                },
            },
        },
        MuiButton: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    textTransform: 'none',
                    color: 'red',
                },
            },
        },
        MuiInputBase: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    color: 'red',
                }
            }
        },
    }
});
```

The UI ends up ugly, but nothing is red, although `textTransform: 'none'` **does** work (the default is `text-transform: uppercase`):

[image: ugly dark UI]

Inspecting a button, I see that my color is in `.css-12w8oxe-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiButton-root` but was overridden by `color: inherit` in `.MuiButtonBase-root`:

[image: Firefox inspector screenshot]

Any idea what's wrong? My outermost component goes something like this:

```
import { StyledEngineProvider, Theme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';

export function App() {
    return (
        // MUI5 migration guide says "JSS <style> elements need to be injected in the 
        // <head> after Emotion <style> elements. ... Inject Emotion before JSS."
        <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DayJS}>
                    <CssBaseline />

                    <Suspense fallback={<LoadingIndicator message="Loading..."/>}>
                        <AppCore/>
                    </Suspense>
                </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </StyledEngineProvider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the Material UI 4.x styling system being loaded at the same time (although I don't know why MUI 5 is using *both* a dynamic class like `.css-12w8oxe-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiButton-root` *and also* MUI 4 class names at the same time).

In my case, it's caused by `MuiPickersUtilsProvider` and/or the v4 date/time pickers. Two solutions come to mind:

1. Migrate all remaining Material UI v4 components [including the date/time pickers](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/pickers-migration/). This can be time-consuming and error-prone, since the pickers API changed a lot.
2. Create two themes and install both of them (using `ThemeProvider` from both '@material-ui/core/styles' and '@mui/material/styles'). The theme object format has changed in v5, but potentially you could create a single v4 object and then use it in both versions of material UI, something like this:

   ```
   import { createTheme, adaptV4Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';
   import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core';

   let v4theme = { ... };
   export const theme_v4 = createMuiTheme(v4theme);
   export const theme = createTheme(adaptV4Theme(v4theme));
   ```

I chose option 1, so I cannot say how well option 2 works. Of course, you probably don't *really* want both versions of MUI loaded, so this would just be a temporary measure to avoid a styling disaster during your migration process.